# DataNuclues (ORM) plugin compatibility App Engine SDK

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin, datanucleus

If you want to use the DataNuclues ORM layer and maintain compatibility with Google App Engine (GWT)... Do you need to install the DataNuclues plugin for eclipse or do you need to use the datanuclues .jar files in the App Engine SDK somehow? Can't find eclipse submenus for the last so.. what should I do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, then the [Google Plugin For Eclipse](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html) should set you up to use the proper jar files.  Those are the correct ones, as I believe that they have been customized for the GAE environment.  (In my WEB-INF/lib, I see jars like datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar, datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar, etc.)

(There is word than update to the datanucleus libraries will be updated soon, see [this datanucleus blog](http://datanucleus.blogspot.com/2011/11/gaej-and-datanucleus-v3-part-2.html).)

Comment: Ah I already found this too: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview.html
But how do you generate entity classes from a database? I don't have to do that by hand right?

Comment: Well, hmm... It sounds like you should read up about the Datastore, which isn't a SQL database at all.  The normal approach to data configuration (or at least "the way that I do it") is to define a POJO class with the proper JDO annotations, and GAE will do the rest.  See http://code.google.com/intl/nl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html

Comment: Aahh I now know this datastore is unique to appengine and is the thing that you should really use instead of a SQL like database if using appengine. But when you don't use appengine (but you dó use for example GWT) you should use for example the datanucleus libraries from their website (install as a plugin for eclipse) and generate/handtype entities from your database.